# MapInfo Pro 15.2 incorrect coordinates when updating column

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, mapinfo

I have an issue getting the correct coordinates when updating the columns, if I double click on the individual object then it comes up with the coordinates in UTM. However, even when I change the map projection to UTM then the coordinates remain the same. I have tried to save the files as a copy and attempt again, but unsure what to do now.

Comment: Every time I change it to the desired WGS 84, it revert back instantly to ETRS Zone 32, even though I had saved this file as a copy so it is editable. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Before any action, you should set "*Session Projection*" as your desired projection in **Options/Preferences/Map Window.../Projection**

[image]

After this, updating the columns with the correct coordinates will work.

Maybe you will find the "Coordinate Extractor" MapBasic tool is more convenient for such updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that, and nothing has changed. The session projection is set to Longtitude / Latitude WGS 84, but still doesn't change no matter which projection I select. Any other ideas?

Comment: I was doing this successfully yesterday (MapInfo 12).
With the map window open, temporarily change the 'session' projection. Then update my data columns with centroidX(obj) & centroidY(obj). Then change the session projection back to what I more commonly use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tool CoordinateExtractor to update your columns with the coordinates.

The tool allows you to choose to coordinate system you want the coordinates extracted using. By default it will use the coordinate system of the table.

You can find the tool in the Tools window.